# Xamarin forms slider behaves weird when bound to

Tags: xaml, xamarin, mvvm, data-binding

I have this issue with slider when the slider is bound to by entry.

I'll try to explain what happens:

When touching to move the slider thumb, the position is all wrong. The first 10% of the slider acts like full range of the slider. If I set the thumb to 10%. The slider jumps to 100%. Same if I put it anywhere between 10 and 100%. If I set the slider to 5%, the slider will set itself to 50%. 
The problem is that where I physically place my finger on the screen, doesn't actually set the slider to that position. (Hope this explains it)

It only happens when the editor text property is bound to the slider.

This works fine:

```
<Slider x:Name="LPslider" Value="{Binding LEDPower, Mode=TwoWay}" Maximum="100" Minimum="0" ValueChanged="LEDPower_Changing" />
<Entry x:Name="ledpow" BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
```

While this doesn't:

```
<Slider x:Name="LPslider" Value="{Binding LEDPower, Mode=TwoWay}" Maximum="100" Minimum="0" ValueChanged="LEDPower_Changing" />
<Entry x:Name="ledpow" BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference LPslider}, Path=Value}"/>
```

Note how: Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference LPslider}, Path=Value}" is causing the weird slider behaviour when it binds the slider value to the entry control.

Anyone have any idea what causes this? Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

This is what happens in the LEDPower_Changing event:

```
    public void LEDPower_Changing(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        double pow = 100; 
        int power;
        string powerValue = "100";

        try
        {
            pow = e.NewValue;
            power = Convert.ToInt32(pow);
            powerValue = power.ToString();

        }
        catch { }

        try
        {
            foreach (string ip in ipad)
            {

                TcpClient client = new TcpClient(ip, 1025);
                if (!client.Connected)
                {
                    client.Connect(ip, 1025);
                }
                Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(":LEDPW" + powerValue + "\r\n");
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                // Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 

                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

                stream.Close();
                client.Close();
            }

        }

        catch { }



    }
```

Comment: Did you handle the logic in `LEDPower_Changing` ? If so , post the full code, which will help us to solve the issue .

Comment: Thanks for the reply Lucas. Im not sure what logic to handle there. I've updated the OP to include what happens in event.

Comment: Try to set the binding as `Text={Binding LEDPower}`

Comment: I tried to set binding to LEDPower: The slider behaves normally, but the value in entry stays at 0. I suppose I need to change the ViewModel for that to work?

Comment: Yes, since you had bind the value of Slider to the property in  ViewModel , It would be better to bind the text of entry to it directly .